# Is there a formula or function to clean away unique identifier in 1 cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

For example, I have a list of data as per Column A. Is there a formula or way to clean up the data so that it will reflect the end product in Column B? Thank you.

[image: Cell A1 contains 3 lines of data. Cell A2 contains 2 lines of data.]

Comment: Is the number important (e.g. to order the text), or are you just trying to discard the # and everything that follows?

Comment: Hi @Chronocidal, nope the order of the text does not matter. I just want to remove the '#xxx' portion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If one has access to `TEXTJOIN` then formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"#"),"#","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 1]"))
```

Or, if you sure all values after `#` are numeric:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"#"),"#","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0!=0]"))
```

**Note:** Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

For more `FILTERXML` "tricks", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)

Comment: Since the id's seem to have a fixed length of 4, wouldn't it be easier to use the LEFT function?

Comment: @GeertBellekens, you are welcome to put an answer down =). It surely is valid, but I don't see how it would be shorter.

Comment: Nah, not really my thing. It just seem much simpler with LEFT so I wondered if there was a reason why you didn't choose for that option.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, the reason is that I'd have to use `FILTERXML` twice. e.g: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),LEN(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))-5))` is a much longer construct =)

Comment: Thanks, in the first image uploaded it wasn't clear there were more then one line in a single cell. Now it makes sense :)

Comment: Hi @GeertBellekens Thank you for the help, it did work! However, can I check if is there a way to amend the formula if my Column A input contains a separator and spaces (e.g. Apples & Oranges#0001 etc)?

Comment: @JxN I'm not the one who helped you, JvdV posted the answer :)

Comment: @JxN, please update your question with representable sample data. The current answer works for the data given. If your data patterns differs, then please make sure to include this along with desired results.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing it out. @JvdV Thank you for looking into it and helping with my question! (:

Comment: No worries, @JxN, but don't forget to update your question as without I can't help you any further.